# How to Compile SFML C++ Source Code From Linux to Windows on a Linux Distro?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, cross-platform, sfml

I've been searching online for solutions for 5 hours and still can't compile on my Linux Distro (openSuSE) to Windows using the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) API.

I can compile non-SFML applications without any problems using the MinGW compiler on openSuSE by invoking this command:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ Main.cpp`

However, whenever I compile a SFML program like this one: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-cb.php

I get this error: `fatal error: SFML\System.hpp: No such file or directory`

I tried:
`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ Main.cpp -L /home/user/Downloads/SFML1.6/lib -lsfml-system`

But I still get the same error.

My IDE is Eclipse Juno and I have installed the toolchain support for cross platform development for CDT in the optional features. Again, trying with Eclipse, my programs compile without any problems not using the SFML API. But once I compile a program using SFML, I get the error. Yes, it working using the GNU G++ with SFML. What I've tried is downloading SFML for Windows from the download page and compile (which is what I've shown previously) but it still does not work.

Comment: Did you try passing something for `-I`?

Comment: Is the SFML library a Linux or a Windows binary?

Comment: No, I did not pass something for "-I" and what should I put in for the -I parameter?

Comment: And the SFML library is Windows binary, it's in my Downloads folder and my Linux binary SFML is in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include/.

Comment: -I is key for preprocessor to find headers.

Comment: It still doesn't work and I use Eclipse as my IDE which should make things easier but it doesn't work when compiling for Windows. What I used to get SFML working on the Linux side is that I had the linker link the libraries "sfml-system" etc. I tried doing the same with compiling for Windows, but it doesn't work. I even set the library search path to /home/user/Downloads/SFML1.6/lib/ and /home/user/Downloads/SFML1.6/include/. It doesn't work.

Comment: I think I MIGHT be missing some important MinGW dependencies? Here's the list of what I currently have installed:http://pastebin.com/PHVFEJNq

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining about `SFML\System.hpp`. Please note the backslash in that. Even though you are targeting the Windows platform, header files should still be using forward slash.

Comment: I am using forward slash to include my header files.